# How can I selectively paginate my Master's Thesis?

Tags: page-numbering, thesis

So basically my institute requires me to :

1) Number pages till Introduction in Roman
   ---  Title page should be unnumbered

2) From Introduction onwards, Arabic numbering
   ---  First page of Introduction should be unnumbered

3) My format is basically

- Title page
- Acknowledgement
- Contents
- List of Tables and Figures
- Nomenclature
- Abstract
- Introduction
- Chapters
- Results
- Conclusion and future work

Pretty complex problem. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: check out the koma-script documentclasses: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/ they do all the stuff mentioned. Use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` to change page numbering style.

Comment: Also, checkout the `memoir` class. I used this for my thesis and was very happy with it. I prepared a basic layout that I used for my thesis. Feel free to use and modify it. https://github.com/tdett/thesis-template. Also, consider learning `git` or `mercurial` for version control.

Comment: Toptesi class allow to adopt your format and has a command to automatically make the Title page. I used this class to build my thesis.
You can find the manual here: [link](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/toptesi/toptesi.pdf.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `book` class, you can do this:

**thesis.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}  %%% put packages you need here
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{1in}
    \Huge This is the title
  \end{titlepage}
  %%----------------------------------------------
  \frontmatter
  \include{acknowledgement}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \listoffigures
  %%put nomeclture command here. I don't know the details of how you do it.
  \include{abstract}
  %%--------------------------------------
  \mainmatter
  \include{introduction}
  \include{what} %% first chapter
  \include{how}  %% second chapter
  \include{results}
  \include{Conclusionandfuture}
  \backmatter
  %% like appendix if any comes here.  
\end{document}
```

In `\include{file name}` the `file name` stands for the file name of your sub-tex files. For example your `introduction.tex` may look like this. I remember that First page of Introduction should be unnumbered.

**introduction.tex**

```
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap:intro}
\thispagestyle{empty}   %%% make first page with no page number
%
Some text here and your introduction starts which has sections
%
\section{some section}
Some text again....
.
.
.
```

And a sample chapter file:

**what.tex**

```
\chapter[What's this?]{What am I doing here?}\label{chap:what}
What are all these......
..
.
.
\section{Motivation}
Some text...
.
.
.
```

Put all thes `.tex` files in the same folder and compile `thesis.tex` file. You may prefer to put sub-files {what.tex, how.tex etc) in a sub folder for neatness in which case you have to use `\include{subfiles/what}` where `subfiles` is the folder that contains `what.tex`. Both `thesis.tex` and `subfiles` folder reside inside the same folder.